# How to define a bean of String array in Spring (using XML configuration)

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to define a Spring bean of type `String[]` and now able to find a way to do so. Sample program is shown below:

```
@Component("sampleClass")
public class SampleClass {
    @Value("#{someArrayId}")
    private String[] someArray;

    public void doWithArray() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(someArray));
    }
}
```

**Spring XML Configuration**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.spring" />

<util:list id="someArrayId">
    <array>
        <value>Tiger</value>
        <value>Lion</value>
    </array>
</util:list>
```

When I am running the program, I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String[] com.demo.spring.SampleClass.someArray; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.String[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.Object[]] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I kind of understand what Spring is complaining, but I don't know how to fix it.

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks, NN

Comment: Well obviously `util:list` is used to create a `List`. You are trying to assign that to a `String[]`. Do you really need an array?

Comment: Yes. The actual use case which I cannot disclose here, requires an array.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know if this is done for a reason, but this configuration

```
<util:list id="someArrayId">
    <array>
        <value>Tiger</value>
        <value>Lion</value>
    </array>
</util:list>
```

is creating a `List` bean that contains one element, a `Object[]` with two `String` values in it.

If you actually wanted a `List` with two `String` values in it, you should have

```
<util:list id="someArrayId">
    <value>Tiger</value>
    <value>Lion</value>
</util:list>
```

in which case you could modify your field to be annotated with

```
@Value("#{someArrayId.toArray(new java.lang.String[0])}")
```

Spring's EL resolver will be able to parse it and execute the corresponding method, which will convert the `List` to a `String[]`.

Alternatively, remove the `@Value` annotation and add a `@Resource` annotated method

```
@Resource(name = "someArrayId")
private void init(List<String> bean) {
    this.someArray = bean.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

I find this cleaner as it's more descriptive.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for the help; `@Value("#{someArrayId.toArray(new java.lang.String[0])}")` is the correct answer. Now, I understand your point of @Resource, I will make similar changes. This thread can be closed now.

Answer (score 15):

instead of `List`, just define array. You can also inject it as configuration to make it less ambiguous. Here another point to note is `value-type` of array.

```
<bean id="sampleClass" class="somePackage.SampleClass">
    <property name="someArray">
        <array value-type="java.lang.String">
            <value>Tiger</value>
            <value>Lion</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 6):

try like this

```
@Component("sampleClass")
public class SampleClass {
    @Value("#{someArrayId.toArray(new String[0])}")
    private String[] someArray;
    ...

<util:list id="someArrayId">
    <value>Tiger</value>
    <value>Lion</value>
</util:list>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering this. This helped saving my day. I can now close this thread.