# Spring Batch - Promoting multiple pieces of data with ExecutionContextPromotionListener

Tags: spring-batch, executioncontext, spring-batch-tasklet

I have a Spring Batch project where I will need to save 2 keys in the `Step` `ExecutionContext`, which will be promoted to the `Job` `ExecutionContext`.

I understand from online examples, e.g. this [code](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-api/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/executioncontextpromotionlistener/executioncontextpromotionlistener-0-0.html) where you can set multiple keys.

This example is done using Java, where the `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` is defined as a Java class. In my case, it's defined in an XML file

Here's the current XML configuration for the promotion listener:

```xml
    <bean id="promotionListener" class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
        <property name="keys" value="idA"/>
    </bean>
```

But i now need another key to be in the `ExecutionContext`.

Is this how i define it?

```xml
    <bean id="promotionListener" class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
        <property name="keys">
            <list>
                <value>idA</value>
                <value>idB</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This doesn't work, so i tried the following but didn't work as the compiler gave an error:

```xml
        <property name="keys" values="idA,idB"/>
```

This doesn't work either

```xml
        <property name="keys" value="idA,idB"/>
```

I couldn't get any online references, even on StackOverflow, for what i'm trying to implement

Appreciate any help, thanks in advance

---

Follow-up questions:

1. Can i use the same `promotionListener` bean in multiple steps?
2. With regards to Q1, i want to have the `promotionListener` bean have a `String` array of keys, one is `idA`, another is `idB`. Can i have Step X save data using `idA` & Step Z save data using `idB`, where both Step X & Z have `promotionListener` as the listeners. Is this allowed? Or should I use 2 separate `promotionListener`s: `promotionListener1` & `promotionListener2` for each of the `Step`s?

Answer (score 1):

The `keys` field in `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`  is of type `String[]`.  So you need to define the keys as an array. This should help: [How to define a bean of String array in Spring (using XML configuration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279020/how-to-define-a-bean-of-string-array-in-spring-using-xml-configuration)

Comment: hi Mahmoud, thanks for your swift response, i have followed what you did, but somehow the data is not getting promoted to the `Job` `ExecutionContext` because when i retrieve the key in the next step, i get `null`. Could you clarify the questions I had? I've added them to my question

Comment: Are you sure the data is correctly *set* in the execution context? (ie that it is not set as `null` in the first place?). For your additional questions: 1) Yes, you can use a prototype bean for that. 2) Yes, same as question 1, but to avoid any confusion, I would use separate listeners with separate keys.

Comment: hi Mahmoud, can you clarify what you mean by the data being correctly set in the execution context? the data i'm putting in the `Step` `ExecutionContext` is not `null`, as the value is retrieved from a DB. i've posted a question on this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77062897/15781733)